# Mapping values of 2 python dictionaries into 1 new list of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries with various translations like this:

```
english = {"word1": 'english_word1', "word2": "english_word2"}
german = {"word1": "german_word1", "word2": "german_word2"}
```

I would like to build a new list of dictionaries out of them that would look like this:

```
translations = [{'EN': 'english_word1', 'DE': 'german_word1'},
 {'EN': 'english_word2', 'DE': 'german_word2'}]
```

With the code I have I'm not getting **german_word1** anywhere, instead getting **german_word2** twice.
This is the result I have at the moment:

```
bad_translations = [{'EN': 'english_word1', 'DE': 'german_word2'},
 {'EN': 'english_word2', 'DE': 'german_word2'}]
```

The code I used:

```
bad_translations = []
lang = ['EN', 'DE']
uk = lang[0]
de = lang[1]
for k,v in english.items():
    for kk, vv in german.items():
        emb = {}
        emb[uk]  = v
        emb[de] = vv
    bad_translations.append(emb)
```

What should I change to get the mappings correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through `german.items()`, but in reality they should be related, since both dictionaries have the same keys.

Instead you might do

```
for k,v in english.items():
    emb = {}
    emb[uk]  = v
    emb[de] = german[k]
    bad_translations.append(emb)
```

so that for every english word with key `k`, you find the matching german word with the same key.

Comment: but this isn't going to output the exact results as what the OP is asking. yes, the 2 dictionaries share the same `k` but if you only use one dictionary i.e. `english` you will only get it's `v`, to use `german[k]` you have to reference the `german` dictionary somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Danny! What would work if they keys are different in some cases?

Comment: If you have different keys, you have to do more work. You might also want to reconsider the 'key' part of your translation. Are "word1" and "word2" supposed to be english words? If so, isn't the dict `german` already a dictionary of translations? The entire question doesn't really make sense if they keys are different.

Comment: @FishingCode if there are keys `k` in `german` that are not in `english`, then there is no translation, and similarly vice versa. Its up to OP to determine what should be done in those cases. If both dicts have the same set of keys, then all is well. OP's original code doesn't try to resolve this, and so neither does my answer

Comment: @FishingCode I'm not sure I understand. My solution produces the correct output assuming `english.keys() == german.keys()`, but that is the best we can do unless OP provides more info. Where am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
english = {"word1": 'english_word1', "word2": "english_word2"}
german = {"word1": "german_word1", "word2": "german_word2"}

lang = ['EN', 'DE']
uk = lang[0]
de = lang[1]


translations = []

for key, word in english.items():
    trans = {uk: english[key], de: german[key]}

    translations.append(trans)

print(translations)
```

For every english word, it creates a dictionary with one key as `'EN'`, with the word from `english`, and another key as `'DE'` with its value in `german`. This dictionary is appended to `translations`.

Comment: Thanks @lionrocker221! That works in the cases where I have exactly the same keys. In some cases keys are different, e.g. "cafe" and "café". What would be the best solution for that?

Comment: @az43 for instance if a key in `english` is `"cafe"` and in `german` it's `"café"`?

Answer (score -1):

The given solutions are great if `english` and `german` have the same set of keys. If you have any partial sets, however, consider:

```py
combined = {}
for k in set(english.keys()).union(german.keys()):
    if k in english:
        combined.setdefault(k, {})['EN'] = english[k]
    if k in german:
        combined.setdefault(k, {})['DE'] = german[k]
```

Note that this changes your data structure somewhat (you end up with `{'word1': {'EN': 'english_word1', 'DE': "german_word1'}}`) but becomes easier to read and reason about.

Comment: Thanks @Adam! Just tried your solution. In some cases my keys are different, e.g. "cafe" and "café". What would be the best solution for that?